average frame number in Lora protocol
I would like to know what is the number of Lora frames used on average during a communication (regardless of the application case) depending on the spreading factor SF?

"average regardless of application case" uh, that will be a very hard to find number, because you would need to know all the devices that exist, how often and how much data they send. And then, you'd have a number that you can't necessarily use for anything; packet size distributions are rarely symmetrical on their average, so what you calculate based on that average has a fair chance of not applying to most devices. So, maybe you want this number to figure out something else. It might help telling us about that!

similar question is what is the average number of steps that a person walks during a shopping trip, regardless of what they are buying?
